# OCommandExecutorNotFoundException creating OrientDB database via jar file

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, maven, orientdb

We want to import data on a Linux system. So we have 2 Java files for the import. One (**OrientDBMain.java**) is for creating an object that is doing all the work. The other (**OrientDB.java**) contains all the database functions like setting an index and so on. The second files starts with:

```
public class OrientDB {
    private OrientGraphFactory factoryGraph;
    private ODatabaseDocumentTx db;
    private String csvPath;

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public OrientDB(String dbPath) {
        OGlobalConfiguration.STORAGE_KEEP_OPEN.setValue(true);
        OGlobalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_CONCURRENT.setValue(false);
        db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx(dbPath).create();
    }
...
```

Running this in **Eclipse** on a **Windows** and **MAC** works **well**. No error and data is correctly imported.

But now we wanted to run this on our Linux system. So we setup a **Maven** project (m2e) and exported a Jar file with all the dependencies here:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>mapegy</groupId>
  <artifactId>orientdbcsv</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>orientdbcsv</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orientdb-graphdb</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <plugins>
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
            <mainClass>mapegy.orientdbcsv.OrientDBMain</mainClass>
          </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
  <configuration>
  <source>${jdk.version}</source>
  <target>${jdk.version}</target>
  </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

But if we run that Jar now we are getting some errors. They say that there is some OCommandExecutorNotFoundException thrown. But how can that be if it run great directly in Eclipse? We have 2 args {pathtoimportdata, pathtodestinationdb}.

```
C:\eclipse-workspace\orientdbcsv\target>java -jar orientdbcsv-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT-jar
-with-dependencies.jar "C:\data" "C:\orientdb-community-2.0-M1\databases\test"
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabase
Exception: Cannot create database
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordAbstract.c
reate(ODatabaseRecordAbstract.java:289)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.create(
ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:61)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseRecordWrapperAbstract.c
reate(ODatabaseRecordWrapperAbstract.java:72)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.create(
ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:56)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseRecordWrapperAbstract.c
reate(ODatabaseRecordWrapperAbstract.java:66)
        at mapegy.orientdbcsv.OrientDB.<init>(OrientDB.java:36)
        at mapegy.orientdbcsv.OrientDBMain.main(OrientDBMain.java:6)
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandExecutorNotFoundExc
eption: Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.select count
(*) from ORole where name.type() not in ["STRING"] and name is not null
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.par
se(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:48)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.par
se(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:33)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.OStorageEmbedded.command(OS
torageEmbedded.java:69)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract
.execute(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:59)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OClassImpl.checkPer
sistentPropertyType(OClassImpl.java:1597)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OClassImpl.addPrope
rty(OClassImpl.java:1911)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OClassImpl.createPr
operty(OClassImpl.java:580)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.security.OSecurityShared.c
reateMetadata(OSecurityShared.java:350)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.security.OSecurityShared.c
reate(OSecurityShared.java:282)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.security.OSecurityProxy.cr
eate(OSecurityProxy.java:70)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.OMetadataDefault.create(OM
etadataDefault.java:84)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordAbstract.c
reate(ODatabaseRecordAbstract.java:269)
        ... 6 more
```

So the question is right now. Why does it throw that error and why does it work properly in Eclipse. And maybe do you know other way to compile import scripts for OrientDB in an easy way with less effort.

Thank you.

Comment: I sent to Fran a email explaining this... check with him tomorrow morning! Nice to meet you.

Comment: Same my friend, thanks for your fast response. Will try it right now, otherwhise cannot sleep. =)

Comment: Talk to Fran is trying also now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because some files are repeated in diferent jars so some config is lost.

The files are:
META-INF/services/com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.functions.OSQLFunctionFactory
META-INF/services/com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLFactory

Try the next pom with shade plugin and try with the generated shaded-jar.jar:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>shaded-jar</finalName>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/services/com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.functions.OSQLFunctionFactory</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/services/com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLFactory</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer   implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>mapegy.orientdbcsv.OrientDBMain</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Well tried it out but getting many warnings with **Maven Install**, http://pastebin.com/G6yHdTL7. That is the current pom.xml now: http://pastebin.com/EtgjgJWN.

Comment: And this is what I get in my cmd console: 
C:\eclipse-workspace\orientdbcsv\target>java -jar shaded-jar.jar "C:\data" "C:\orientdb-community-2.0-M1\databases\test"
no main manifest attribute, in shaded-jar.jar

Comment: Comment the maven-assembly-plugin content to remove some warnings and review the shade messages. Anyway just run with java -jar shaded-jar.jar and see

Comment: I will update to show you how to configure the main class... let me one second.

Comment: Now, try again.. with this configuration... see the ManifestResourceTransformer added in the config!!

Comment: Hey it works great now! Thank you very much. But the warnings stay. Hopefully they don't harm the import process. We'll test it in more detail tomorrow. You saved many wasted hours. Again thanks and have a good night.